# Check server load ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, performance-testing, remote-server

I have an **Asp.NET** Web Form app on a remote server. This server has multiple other app-s. During the day my app works **very slow** and I think the reason is that the other apps use storage, and the server is getting slower. At **night** the app working visibly **faster**. How can I investigate this problem or how to check the server load.

Answer (score 0):

Record your app response time during the 24-hour period. At the same time, record CPU and memory utilization for every application process running on the server. After that analyze the two sets of graphs to find a correlation between them. You may be able to isolate a single resource-hungry application process that slows down your web form app.

To collect performance data, use an on-premise load testing tool with Windows process monitoring capabilities, such as our
[StresStimulus](http://www.stresstimulus.com/). It has a free version.